# Designing a main activity

Tags: gui-design, android

My Android app has about 5-6 main actions such as messages, photos, etc. I am trying to design a main activity that will link to those actions and I'm not sure how should it be designed.

I have considered a few buttons, but I am not sure how comfortable it when using more than 4 actions and whether or not it'll fit in the page.

What is usually done in this case when using Android?

Comment: Could you upload a mockup image of what you've got designed so far, and someone here could link it in for you. That would help a lot.

Comment: It would help if you could better outline the goal(s) of the app.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's a bit late, but, if your *actions* are performed into their own activity, in your case I think you could implement the [Navigation-Drawer pattern](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html).

> The navigation drawer is a panel that transitions in from the left edge of the screen and displays the app’s main navigation options.

more:

> You can also use them at deeper levels in the navigation hierarchy, allowing users to **switch to your app's most important screens from anywhere in the app**.

Following the same pattern, there's also a good OpenSource library that does its job really well:
http://www.androidviews.net/2012/11/sliding-menu/
https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/